# Starting from Minkowski’s inequality for sums, obtain Minkowski’s inequality for integrals

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Minkowski’s inequality for sums:

Let $x_{i}\geq{}0, y_{i}\geq{}0, i = 1,\dotsc,n$. Then

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}+y_{i})^{p}\right)^{1/p}\leq{}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{p}\right)^{1/p}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^{p}\right)^{1/p}$$
when $p>1$, and
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}+y_{i})^{p}\right)^{1/p}\geq{}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{p}\right)^{1/p}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^{p}\right)^{1/p}$$
when $p<1,p\neq{}0$.

Starting from Minkowski’s inequality for sums, obtain Minkowski’s inequality for integrals:
$$\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f+g|^{p}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}\leq{}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f|^{p}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}+\left(\int_{a}^{b}|g|^{p}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}$$
if $f,g\in{}\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ and $p\geq{}1$. Show that this inequality reverses direction if $0 < p < 1$.

I want to use the definition of Riemann sum/integral, but I don't know how to handle the $\varDelta x$ part.

Comment: take the $\Delta x_i$ inside as ${\Delta x_i}^{1/p}$ and then use minkowski.

Comment: @yonatan Thanks. The conditions of Minkowski’s inequality for sums are $x_i\geq{}0,y_i\geq{}0$. If $a<b$, since $|f|\geq 0,|g|\geq 0,|f+g|\geq 0, \varDelta x_i > 0$, we obtain the Minkowski’s inequality for integrals. Similarly, if $b<a$, we have $$\left(\int_{b}^{a}|f+g|^{p}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}\leq{}\left(\int_{b}^{a}|f|^{p}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}+\left(\int_{b}^{a}|g|^{p}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}\implies$$

Comment: $$\left(-\int_{a}^{b}|f+g|^{p}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}\leq \left(-\int_{a}^{b}|f|^{p}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}+\left(-\int_{a}^{b}|g|^{p}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p},$$ so we may assume that $a<b$, is it right?

Comment: Sure, I think we should assume a<b.